# Getting a crash in NSTask

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've had a report from the field of a crash at `-launch` on NSTask.

The code in question is:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/zsh"];
if(ignore)
{
    [task setArguments:@[scriptPath, recordingFolder, Argument]];
}
else
{
    [task setArguments:@[scriptPath, recordingFolder]];
}

NSPipe *outPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:outPipe];

NSPipe *errorPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardError:errorPipe];

[task launch];
```

The scriptPath is a script that is included in the app bundle.
The crash says:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to set posix_spawn_file_actions for fd -1 at index 0 with errno 9'
```

What could be the cause of this? What file descriptor do the posix_spawn_file_actions refer to? Does it mean that the executable script is wrong or that the outPipe or errPipe are not well formed?

I believe it is referring to the posix_spawn function:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/posix_spawn.2.html

And errno 9 is EBADF (bad file number).

Answer (score 7):

I've got a similar error , after I use below command, it's OK, you can try it.

```
NSFileHandle *file=[outPipe fileHandleForReading];
[task launch];
....//read file.
//this is the most important.
[file closeFile];
```

Comment: This actually a fixed same problem for me (I was looping trough many NSTasks).

Answer (score 4):

If you are calling this code many different times sequentially, you are running out of file descriptors -- you need to close the pipes after you are done. The correct way to do it is to deallocate NSTask and it will close the file channels. Put the NSTask-related code in an autoreleasepool statement:

```
@autoreleasepool {
  NSTask* task = [NSTask new];
  ...
  [task launch];
  ...
  [task waitUntilDone];
}
```

Comment: I have an Automator task that is throwing the Posix error: now I have some idea why. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the issue in the question, I suggest that we should put the code of CreateProcess() in an @autoreleasepool block as Apple's doc shows that we should not send -[closeFile] to fileHandleForReading explicitly.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspipe/1414352-filehandleforreading?language=objc

> Declaration
>
> @property(readonly, retain) NSFileHandle *fileHandleForReading;
>
> Discussion
>
> The descriptor represented by this object is deleted, and the object
>   itself is automatically deallocated when the receiver is deallocated.
>
> You use the returned file handle to read from the pipe using
>   NSFileHandle's read methods—availableData, readDataToEndOfFile, and
>   readDataOfLength:.
>
> You don’t need to send closeFile to this object or explicitly release
>   the object after you have finished using it.